# Python subclass with C++ baseclass

Tags: c++, python, swig

I have some C++ I have exposed to [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) through [SWIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG). In there is a base class with a single pure virtual function.

In Python, I import my module and define a class that uses the abstract class as base.

```
import mymodule
class Foo(mymodule.mybase):
    ...
```

In that module is also a manager class, I want to add my new defined class to the manager.

```
m = mymodule.mymanager()
m.add(Foo())
```

Definition of add:

```
void add(mybase* b) { ... }
```

Didn't work as I would expect:

```
TypeError: in method 'mymanager_add', argument 2 of type 'mymodule::mybase *'
```

What did I miss? It seems it's not sure that my Foo class is a "mybase". I tried adding a call to the base class constructor in Python but that didn't work, said the class was abstract.

```
def __init__(self):
    mymodule.mybase.__init__(self)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `Foo` is not derived from `mybase` in the eyes of the C++ environment.  I'm not sure if SWIG can pull this off since it requires a bidirectional understanding of inheritance - Python class uses C++ class as base and C++ code recognizes the inheritance relationship.  I would take a serious look into Boost.python since it seems to support the functionality that you are after.  [Here's an entry on wiki.python.org about it.](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/Inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but you might have better luck with [boost.python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/Inheritance). Don't know how much work it would be for you to switch, but you could probably get a simple inheritence test case for your problem going pretty quickly.

Comment: I tried boost first. It took an extremely long time to install and at the end I couldnt get it to work anyway. Im at a different workstation now and hesitate take on that behemoth again. You dont happen to know if there is a quick and easy way to install "just" boost.python?

Comment: What platform are you on? I would have thought on linux/mac you could get it through your package manager/macports. Otherwise I'm afraid I don't but http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/python/doc/building.html has a 'No-install quickstart' section...